# setCellValue in phpExcel

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I want to export a report to Excel. Now it's little okay. I'm stuck in setCellValue. I want to take all the values using loop. In final, after looping I want a sum row. That is the sum of all columns.

**Code**

```
        $row = 2;
        $no = 1;
        foreach($p_det as $n){
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row,$no);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$row,$n->student_id);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$row,$n->reg_fee);

     $row++;
        $no++;
    }

     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row+1,'SUM');
```

I add this last line, my export is not working.

Comment: So what is the problem with your code? is there any error displaying?

Comment: can i put this  setCellValue outside the loop..?

Comment: Of course you can. You just need to specify the correct cell name only. I couldn't see any issue with your code. If the code with in the loop id working, then the outside loop code too will work.

Comment: the pblm in $row+1.i put 8 instead of $row+1..Export is working..how to get the next row after looping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the line

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row+1,'SUM');
```

With the below one

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.($row+1),'SUM');
```

It will work

With the `()`, it will clearly extract the single numeric value. With out the parenthesis, it may make issues.

Comment: thank u very much sir.just begining.I'm doing this.Can i ask any doubt in this  on pogress

Comment: With pleasure. Always keep in mind this. If you append with some calculations, do it in this way.

Comment: sir one more..can i put some designs like tble structure

Comment: You can do almost all the things that you can done in "MS Excel" you will get the documentation from https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/documentation and helps from stackoverflow

Comment: ok.i will check it..plz check my img attached..then i want transport in one row.the next two split like term and fee in next row

Comment: There is `mergeCells()` function for the purpose. Just google and you will get the  help.

Comment: sir,im doing this    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('O1:P1');

Comment: how to set value in that

Comment: @robins, $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('O1','Your value'');

Comment: Why don't you read the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation)? Or look at some of the [examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Examples)?

Comment: i tried it..but it doesnt work..thats why i'm asking

Comment: Well the way Stack Overflow works is that when you have a question, you ask a question (preferably showing what you've tried to do, what you expected, and what you actually got)..... but you don't keep asking questions in comments against a previous answer;  new question should be exactly that, a new question